# What Populates the Sylius Resource Metadata Registry?

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

Short Version: What populates the `sylius.resource_registry` service with data?

Long Version: Sylius, (a PHP ecommerce framework built using Symfony) uses [Symfony's custom route loading system](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html) to load some additional routes based on special configuration values.  The custom route loader class name is [`Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Routing\ResourceLoader`](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/57227a9a7bcd18b93218ec1f4902f7f48119a802/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Routing/ResourceLoader.php).

There's logic in this resource loader that looks for an alias ([example value of an  alias](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/57227a9a7bcd18b93218ec1f4902f7f48119a802/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminApiBundle/Resources/config/routing/zone.yml#L7)), and then [uses that alias to load metadata from a registry](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/57227a9a7bcd18b93218ec1f4902f7f48119a802/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Routing/ResourceLoader.php#L67).

```
$metadata = $this->resourceRegistry->get($configuration['alias']);
```

This registry is a symfony service with the identifier `sylius.resource_registry`, [configured here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/57227a9a7bcd18b93218ec1f4902f7f48119a802/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Resources/config/services.xml#L37).

```
#File: vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Resources/config/services.xml

<service id="sylius.resource_registry" class="Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\Registry" public="false" />
```

and [injected here](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/57227a9a7bcd18b93218ec1f4902f7f48119a802/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Resources/config/services/routing.xml#L19).

```
#File: vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/Resources/config/services/routing.xml
<service id="sylius.routing.loader.resource" class="Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Routing\ResourceLoader" public="false">
    <argument type="service" id="sylius.resource_registry" />
    <argument type="service">
        <service class="Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Routing\RouteFactory" />
    </argument>
    <tag name="routing.loader" />
</service>
```

However, [the `Sylius\Component\Resource\Metadata\Registry` class has no constructor](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/57227a9a7bcd18b93218ec1f4902f7f48119a802/src/Sylius/Component/Resource/Metadata/Registry.php#L1), so it's not clear what populates the private $metadata array.  There are methods named `add` and `addFromAliasAndConfiguration` which ~mutate the state~ adds values to the `$metadata` array, but it's not clear what code calls these methods, and/or what sylius configuration causes those methods to be called.

After chasing this down as far as I have, I'm not sure how deep this rabbit hole goes, so I turn to you Stack Overflow: What populates the `sylius.resource_registry` service with data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Symfony compiler pass does it. Specifially: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ResourceBundle/DependencyInjection/Compiler/RegisterResourcesPass.php

It loads the configuration from `sylius.resources` Symfony container parameter and it adds a method call to `addFromAliasAndConfiguration` to service definition of `sylius.resource_registry` for every resource it finds in `sylius.resources`.

Comment: +1 useful!  Thank you!  Do you happen to know where the configuration for these values actually resides?  i.e. the `...\RegisterResourcePass` class does the work and Symfony knows about this class via a Symfony Bundle's DepdendencyInjection Extension ... but ultimately where does the data come from?

Comment: Hello guys! There are two types of resources in Sylius: built-in models coming from the core and custom models created by the app's developer. So for a built-in model like Channel, it's https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ChannelBundle/DependencyInjection/SyliusChannelExtension.php#L33 and https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/ChannelBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L54. For custom models it's same configuration schema: https://docs.sylius.com/en/1.4/cookbook/entities/custom-model.html. (under sylius_resource)